# What Port is Squid Running on in OS X/BSD

Tags: osx, bsd, netstat, squid

I've recently starting playing around with the Squid caching server on my OS X based computer.  I'm curious if there's a way to tell which port Squid is running on using `netstat` or other standard unix commands.

That is, I know Squid runs by default on port `3128`, but if I **didn't know this** or someone had started Squid listening on a different port via a configuration file I couldn't access or find, would there be a way to determine which port is was listening on.

Some rudimentary googling turning up the following `netstat` command for machines running Linux

```
$ netstat -plant
```

But running this on OS X threw an error

```
$ netstat -plant
netstat: lant: unknown or uninstrumented protocol
```

I assume this is some BSD/Linux difference, but not knowing my networking well enough, I don't have the ability to figure out what the correct BSD invocation would be.

OS 10.10 if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listing the open files with -i should show you the ports in use

```
lsof -i
```

If there's too much output

```
lsof -i | grep squid
```

Works with Linux & OS X

Comment: Thank you for your answer -- but I'm afraid I'm not following it completely.  If I run `lsof -i` and grep for `squid`, I get the following output (https://gist.github.com/astorm/5d238d26faa66de23851).  This doesn't (seem to) mention port `3128` anywhere, and I'm sure squid is running on this port since I've been able to connect to it and use it.   Am I misinterpreting the data somehow?

Comment: And for anyone following along at home, `lsof -i -P` did the trick.

Comment: Strange on our Ubuntu Squid server the -P is not needed, maybe an OS X thing or perhaps it's because we have active connections.  Anyway, glad it pointed you in the right direction

Comment: If you're curious -- BSD seems to have a concept of named ports -- without the -P the port name is shown -- with `-P` the numerical port is shown.

Answer (score 1):

In BSD `netstat` `-p` is protocol, whereas it is *program* in the `netstat` from net-tools, the BSD version appears to have no equivalent. `man` is almost always your friend in these cases.

BSD has `sockstat` which gets you what you want but this is does not appear to be there on the OS X I have  access to.

As already mentioned `lsof` is probably your most cross platform way of getting the result you want. add `-n` to stop port numbers being converted to names and confusing you with *ndl-aas* where you are expecting 3128.

Comment: I know the -n specifics would have worked better in a comment, but for now I can only comment on my own posts.